# cocoapodsのサンプルによくあるタッチが見えるやつの作り方

Tags: swift, cocoapods

こんにちは。
xcode初心者です。
画面をタッチすると表示される？もの。離すと消えて、タッチし続けたらずっと丸が表示される。といったものを作りたいと思っています。
Cocoapodsのサンプルとかでよく見るのですが、どのように作ればいいのでしょうか？
また、指一本ならひとつ、3本なら三つ指の置いた場所に丸やアニメーションが表示されるようにしたいです。
とりあえず今は、UIGestureRecognizerDelegateを使ってタッチしたらラベルにカウントされる。longタッチしたら押しはじめにstart 終わったらendとラベルに表示させるということをやってみました。
グダグダですみません。何かアドバイスいただけたらと思います。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

OSSライブラリでよければこういったものがあります
https://github.com/morizotter/TouchVisualizer